# While loop restart if condition isn't meant

Tags: bash, if-statement, while-loop, scripting

I'm trying to get this script to loop back and restart if the user inputs a response that does not match the choices allowed but then enters a correct response the second time around. I tried using continue, but it loops infinitely. Any thoughts?

`

```
#!/bin/bash

#Obtaing user selection and input
echo " Gathering list of users on this machine..."
sleep 2
echo "$( ls /Users )" 
echo "From the list above, which user did you want to work with?"
read userSelection
echo "What is that user's password?"

#Hiding User's Password
stty -echo
read userSelectionPassword
stty echo
echo "Did you want [enable], [disable], or check the current [status] of Secure Token for $userSelection?"
read taskSelection


#Converting input to lowercase
taskSelectionLower=$(echo $taskSelection | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')


#Running commands
while [ true ]
do
if [[ $taskSelectionLower == "enable" ]]; then
    echo "Enabling..."
    echo "$(sysadminctl -adminUser AdminUser -adminPassword AdminPass -secureTokenOn $userSelection -password $userSelectionPassword)"
    break
elif [[ $taskSelectionLower == "status" ]]; then
    echo "Displaying $userSelection current Secure Token status..."
    echo "$( sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus $userSelection )"
    break
elif [[ $taskSelectionLower == "disable" ]]; then
    echo "Disabling..."
    echo "$(sysadminctl -adminUser AdminUser -adminPassword AdminPass -secureTokenOff $userSelection -password $userSelectionPassword)"
    break
else
    echo "Incorrect selection made..."
    echo "Did you want [enable], [disable], or check the current [status] of Secure Token for $userSelection?"
    read taskSelection
    exit
fi

done
```

`

Attempted using continue at the end of the condition, but loops infinitely.

Expected outcome would be for the for loop to restart, allowing the user to input a correct response and get the correct output.

Comment: `[ true ]` always succeeds because `true` is a non-empty string. `while [ false ]; do` would work exactly the same way. You can execute the *command* `true` with `while  true; do `, or use the standard command `:` that always succeeds: `while :; do`.

Comment: You are reading a new value for `taskSelection`, but never redefine the value of `taskSelectionLower`, which is what all your checks look at.

Comment: (And `exit` would cause your script to exit without repeating the loop at all, anyway.)

Comment: @chepner Thank you that was it!!!! Now I got to figure out how to implement a list that will store values returned by the system. Wish me luck!!

Answer (score 0):

The `select` command was designed exactly for this sort of interactive script.

Some hopefully useful observations -

```
echo " Gathering list of users on this machine..." 
sleep 2 # why?
```

This `sleep` seems to serve no purpose but to annoy the user.

```
echo "$( ls /Users )"  # why?? Don't do this.
```

This is exactly the same as

```
ls /Users # same output. Keep it simple.
```

Also, since you are `bash` instead of `sh`, rather than

```
taskSelectionLower=$(echo $taskSelection | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
```

try declaring the variable as lowercase -

```
declare -l taskSelectionLower
read taskSelectionLower
```

or handle it with [parameter parsing syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) -

```
read taskSelectionLower
taskSelectionLower="${taskSelectionLower,,}"
```

but why let them possibly mistype at all?
Consider using a `select` statement.

Rather than building your own loop, presenting options, worrying about formatting, etc, let tools that already do that handle it for you.

My rewrite using `echo` to show the commands to be executed - take those out and it should run fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /c/Users
echo "Please select a valid user from this system."
select u in */; do
  if [[ -d "$u" ]]
  then userSelection="${u%/}"; break
  else echo "Please enter a number from the presented options."
  fi
done # get just the username
cd $OLDPWD # if needed
admSet() { # no reason to ask for the password just to get status...
  read -sp "what's $userSelection's password? " userSelectionPassword
  echo # reading the password leaves the cursor on the previous line
  echo sysadminctl -adminUser AdminUser -adminPassword AdminPass \
         -secureToken$1 "$userSelection" -password "$userSelectionPassword"
}
select taskSelection in enable disable status; do # case is controlled
  case "$taskSelection" in
    status) echo "Displaying $userSelection current Secure Token status..."
            echo sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus $userSelection ;;
    enable) echo "Enabling..."  ; admSet On  ;;
   disable) echo "Disabling..." ; admSet Off ;;
         *) echo "Please enter a number from the presented options."
            continue ;;
  esac
  break
done
```